# Get option value from select tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select tag on my page. I want to get the value 1 from `<option value="1">` here using jquery to process an ajax request. How can I get so?

Here is a sample code

```
<select name="duration">
    <option value='01'>This is Value 1</option>
    <option value='02'>This is Value 2</option>
    <option value='03'>This is Value 3</option>
    <option value='04'>This is Value 4</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the 01, 02, 03 or 04 (whichever is selected in case) from the select tag. How can I do so?

I tried using `$("select[name='duration'] option:selected").text()` but this returns me `This is Value 1` instead of `01` (the actual field value). Please help.

Comment: You need `.val()`

Comment: wow you never used google or even a documentation before or i am wrong? Stackoverflow inst for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[name='duration']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.duration').change(function(){
var a = $("select[name='duration'] option:selected").text();
var b = $("select[name='duration'] option:selected").val();

});

});
</script>
<select class="duration" name="duration">
    <option value='01'>This is Value 1</option>
    <option value='02'>This is Value 2</option>
    <option value='03'>This is Value 3</option>
    <option value='04'>This is Value 4</option>
</select>
</html>
```